# Flutter: how can I call method from another class?

Tags: function, flutter, dart

I am new in Dart and Flutter.  Now  I am having a problem with calling a method from another class.

I have tried to make the method static, but the method contains setState() method so it is not possible.

So I have to call `main.dart` >>> `showDialogWith()` from `wallet.dart`

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dialog/operation.dart';
import 'pages/wallet.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future showDialogWith(String dialogName) async {
    Widget dialog;
    switch (dialogName) {
      case 'operations':
        setState(() {
          dialog = OperationsDialog();
        });
        break;
        // another cases and default...
    }
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: dialog,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   body: WalletContent();
  }
}
```

wallet.dart

```
class WalletContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // here I have to call the 'showDialogWith()' method
      },
    );
  }
}
```

operation.dart

```
class OperationsDialog extends StatefulWidget{
  OperationsDialog({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OperationDialogState createState() => new _OperationDialogState();
}

class _OperationDialogState extends State<OperationsDialog> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SimpleDialog(
      title: new Text('Операции', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function as a parameter.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  body: WalletContent(showDialogWith);
}
```

Add a Function field into your `WalletContent` and assign it to your MaterialButton

```
class WalletContent extends StatelessWidget {
  WalletContent(this.onPressed);

  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () => onPressed(...), // Pass your desired string here
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Didn't know that it is possible to pass functions as parameter. Thanks a lot!!!